# Gonna "miss me by the hair"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms, lyrics

Is the phrase miss someone *by something* an actual phrase as in [the song Cups](https://youtu.be/cmSbXsFE3l8?t=1m30s)?

> When I’m gone
>   When I’m gone
>   You’re gonna miss me when I’m gone
>   You’re gonna miss me by my hair
>   You’re gonna miss me everywhere, oh
>   *You’re gonna miss me when I’m gone*

I understand it as "you'll recognize you miss me when you recall my hair".

Comment: Are you sure you heard it / it was transcribed correctly?

Comment: All lyrics on the internet have it the same

Comment: @bigbadmouse I've added a link to the music video - the lyrics are accurate as far as I can tell.

Comment: thank you, it wasnt one I'm familiar with and I'm not allowed to go to those sites from work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not only *miss me by my hair* but also *miss me by my walk … miss me by my talk…* later in the song. This is not a conventional use of *by*, at least in standard English. It may have dialectical origins; the song was first recorded by the Carter Family in 1931, and has other colloquialisms like *two bottle 'a whiskey for the way*.

I would interpret it as an extended use of *by* in the sense of the object of concern, and thus roughly equivalent to saying *you're going to miss me because of my hair [because my hair will be gone with me]*. In other words, *you're gonna miss me, with respect to my hair*, and *you're gonna miss me, as regards my walk*, and *you're gonna miss me, vis-à-vis my talk*.

But by the same token, it could be an extension of *by* as an axis or parameter (*sort the applicants by grade point average*; *you're gonna miss me when you compare the attractiveness of my hair against that of peers who will not be going*), or extent (*too heavy by half a kilo*; *you're gonna miss me as my hair is estimated at 176 international affection units, so my departure will increase your overall loneliness score by at least 176 IAU*).

---

Song lyrics, like poetry, are not required to conform to any standards of grammar, usage, pronunciation, and so forth. They are an artistic expression, paired with music. They may tell a story, or they may try to evoke an emotional response, but they might also be thrown in simply because they conform to a certain rhythm or rhyme. In other words, they don't have to "make sense" on their own and there is often no point in attempting to do so.

Read lyrics to improve your enjoyment of a song, or to appreciate their artistry on their own, but do not look to them to learn English. A far better place to practice your skills would be at one of the innumerable websites devoted to discussing and debating the meanings of song lyrics.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no. Please don't use that as an idiomatic expression, it will sound strange. It looks like it was used simply to make the lyrics rhyme.

Comment: It's not an actual phrase in my British English dialect.